Why is R inline code not executed in Quarto in some situations?
I am switching from Rmarkdown to Quarto and have encountered a wired behaviour:
Here is a simple example. When I render it, the inline R code Sys.Date() is not executed.
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

Today is `r Sys.Date()`.


A variation of inline code defined in Quarto, {r} Sys.Date() is not working either:


But as long as there is an R code chunk (even if it is empty), the inline R code will be executed:

Or, as #4855 suggested, by adding engine: knitr in the YAML part, it also works:

It's a bit confusing for someone who just switched from RMarkdown to Quarto. Because I would assume the prefix r in the inline code chunk is sufficient for quarto to tell I am using R, not Python.
Can someone explain why this happens? Many thanks.

The syntax for inline Quarto code is different and requires curly braces. See the docs: https://quarto.org/docs/computations/inline-code.html#:~:text=The%20syntax%20for%20inline%20code,Knitr

Thank you, I have read it but It doesn't work either. Please see the updated second example in the question.

The reason for this behavior is explained in the github page you linked.  Quarto documents that don't use R are unable to use inline expressions beginning with r  if the knitr engine is auto-bound by default.  So, the engine is not auto-bound unless there is an R code block in the document or the document file extension is .Rmd.  If you don't have R code blocks in the document and are using the .qmd extension you need to specify the engine in the document YAML, as you have already noted.

Check the engine binding part of the inline code on the Quarto documentation.

Thanks for showing that an R chunk is what is required to render inline code! When I use the argument echo=FALSE, it renders the inline code without showing the chunk. THANK YOU!

It worked when YAML: engine: knitr and not using curly braces around r as advised on Quarto page i.e.
`r radius` not `{r} radius`


There is an easy solution to this problem. Change your YAML Header as follows:
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

Now your code will work even without adding any R code chunk.
The issue is that when there is no code chunk, Quarto cannot determine which engine to use: knitr or ipynb. So, when you specify knitr engine, the in-line code will also be evaluated using knitr.

Thank you. But why can't quarto tell which one I am using via the keyword r in the inline code?
